# how to sum successive elements of a dataframe with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,5,3, 2,1,2, 5,1,4, 8,6,7, 1,6,3])
```

I'd like to create a dataframe with the sum of every three successive elements in `df`

```
9
5
10
21
10
```

Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

Comment: For your specific case, `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).sum()`

Comment: @ayhan: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.